# WeakTypeTag not working when package object extends trait

Tags: scala

Consider this contrived example with `WeakTypeTag`s:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag
import reflect.runtime.universe.weakTypeOf

package object stackoverflow1 {
  sealed trait Status
  trait Open extends Status
  trait Closed extends Status

  case class Buffer[S <: Status](available: Int)
  object Buffer {
    def create(available: Int): Buffer[Open] = new Buffer[Open](available)
    def from[S <: Status: WeakTypeTag](b: Buffer[S]): Buffer[Open] = {
      weakTypeOf[S] match {
        case t if t <:< weakTypeOf[Open]   => b.asInstanceOf[Buffer[Open]]
        case t if t <:< weakTypeOf[Closed] => new Buffer[Open](b.available)
      }
    }
  }
}

package stackoverflow1 {
  object Main extends App {
    val b1 = Buffer.create(1024)
    val b2 = Buffer.from(b1)
  }
}
```

This works fine, but it does not work anymore when I move the code of the package object into a trait and mix that trait into the package object:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag
import reflect.runtime.universe.weakTypeOf

package stackoverflow2 {
  trait Mixin {
    sealed trait Status
    trait Open extends Status
    trait Closed extends Status

    case class Buffer[S <: Status](available: Int)
    object Buffer {
      def create(available: Int): Buffer[Open] = new Buffer[Open](available)
      def from[S <: Status: WeakTypeTag](b: Buffer[S]): Buffer[Open] = {
        weakTypeOf[S] match {
          case t if t <:< weakTypeOf[Open]   => b.asInstanceOf[Buffer[Open]]
          case t if t <:< weakTypeOf[Closed] => new Buffer[Open](b.available)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

package object stackoverflow2 extends Mixin

package stackoverflow2 {
  object Main extends App {
    val b1 = Buffer.create(1024)
    val b2 = Buffer.from(b1)
  }
}
```

ErrorMessage:
`Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: stackoverflow2.Open (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassNoArgsTypeRef)?`

Some ideas why?

**EDIT**

With abstract type member instead of type parameter:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

package stackoverflow3 {
  trait Mixin {
    sealed trait Status
    trait Open extends Status
    trait Closed extends Status

    case class Buffer(available: Int) {
      type S <: Status
      def withStatus[S <: Status] = asInstanceOf[BufferAux[S]]
    }
    type BufferAux[S0 <: Status] = Buffer { type S = S0 }
    object Buffer {
      def create(available: Int): BufferAux[Open] = Buffer(available).withStatus[Open]
      def from[S <: Status: WeakTypeTag](b: BufferAux[S]): BufferAux[Open] = {
        weakTypeOf[S] match {
          case t if t <:< weakTypeOf[Open]   => b.asInstanceOf[BufferAux[Open]]
          case t if t <:< weakTypeOf[Closed] => Buffer(b.available).withStatus[Open] // no need for creating new Buffer, only shows intend
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

package object stackoverflow3 extends Mixin

package stackoverflow3 {
  object Main extends App {
    val b1 = Buffer.create(1024)
    val b2 = Buffer.from(b1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's add some debug printing to the `Buffer.from` method:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.showRaw
println(s"scrut = ${weakTypeOf[S]}, ${showRaw(weakTypeOf[S])}")
println(s"Open = ${weakTypeOf[Open]}, ${showRaw(weakTypeOf[Open])}")
println(s"Closed = ${weakTypeOf[Closed]}, ${showRaw(weakTypeOf[Closed])}")
```

This will print out the types in question and their structure. Maybe that will explain what's going on:

```
scrut = stackoverflow2.Open, TypeRef(SingleType(ThisType(stackoverflow2), stackoverflow2.package), TypeName("Open"), List())
Open = Mixin.this.Open, TypeRef(ThisType(stackoverflow2.Mixin), TypeName("Open"), List())
Closed = Mixin.this.Closed, TypeRef(ThisType(stackoverflow2.Mixin), TypeName("Closed"), List())
```

Allright, this shows fully-qualified versions of the types in question, and that reveals the difference that might be the problem. So, reflection is saying that `stackoverflow2.Open` is not subtype of `Mixin.this.Open`. Hmm, but the package object `stackoverflow2` extends `Mixin`. That must be a bug in reflection, right?

Let's ask the third party and check what scalac has to say about it. How about we write something like `val test: Mixin.this.Open = (??? : stackoverflow2.Open)` inside `Buffer.from` and try to compile?

```
Test.scala:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : stackoverflow2.Open
 required: Mixin.this.Open
        val test: Open = (??? : stackoverflow2.Open)
                              ^
one error found
```

Okay, scalac actually agrees with reflection, so maybe it's not a bug. And it's not a bug indeed, because if we create another subclass of `Mixin`, then that one will have its own copy of `Mixin.this.Open`, which will be incompatible with `stackoverflow2`'s copy of `Mixin.this.Open`. This means that `stackoverflow2.Open` is rightfully not a subtype of `Mixin.this.Open`.

We have several options here.

First, instead of `t <:< weakTypeOf[Open]` we could just write `t <:< weakTypeOf[stackoverflow2.Open]`. Not pretty, because this puts the knowledge about subclasses into a superclass.

Second, we can use `asSeenFrom` on `weakTypeOf[Open]` to adjust `Mixin.this.Open` to the container of the type that's passed into `from`. That will appease the subtype checker, because then it will compare apples from one tree to apples from the same tree, so to speak:

```
type InternalType = scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable#Type
type ApiType = Type
val pre = weakTypeOf[S].asInstanceOf[InternalType].prefix.asInstanceOf[ApiType]
val topen = weakTypeOf[Open].asSeenFrom(pre, symbolOf[Mixin])
...
case t if t <:< topen => b.asInstanceOf[Buffer[Open]]
...
```

Third, we can roll a manual check that verifies that: a) the type we've passed is declared in a subtype of `Mixin` and b) the name of the underlying symbol is `Open` or `Closed`. That seems to be easier than the second option, but actually I wouldn't recommend going for it, because it's easy to overlook some corner case when reimplementing something like this yourself. For instance, the recipe provided above is actually wrong, because in addition to a) and b) we also need to check that c) the underlying symbol is inherited from `Mixin`, not redefined (i.e. shadowed). There might very well be something else that I'm overlooking, so the third option is definitely the riskiest one.

Comment: Great! But seems to me it's not working when I choose to have an abstract type member instead of a type parameter for `Buffer`, i.e.: `case class Buffer(available: Int) { type S <: Status }`. Do you have a solution for abstract type member, too?

Comment: Then instead of `weakTypeOf[S]` you have to use `weakTypeOf[S].typeSymbol.info`. No idea why that's the case, but otherwise it won't work - the compiler infers weakTypeOf[S] to be b1.S, and it won't dealias or normalize it into `Open`. The typeSymbol trick works, fortunately.